# SQL Group By Throwing Up Error (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL code that throws up an error saying

> Error: SQLCODE=-119, SQLSTATE=42803, SQLERRMC=WONUM

The code works fine until I add the group by:

```
  select *
  from workorder 
  left join labtrans on  labtrans.refwo=workorder.wonum and labtrans.siteid=workorder.siteid
  left join matusetrans on workorder.wonum=matusetrans.refwo and workorder.siteid=matusetrans.tositeid  and linetype not in (select value from synonymdomain where domainid='LINETYPE' and maxvalue='TOOL')
  left join  locations  on locations.location = workorder.location and locations.siteid=workorder.siteid
  left join person on personid in (select personid from labor where laborcode = labtrans.laborcode)
  left join po on workorder.wonum=po.hflwonum and workorder.siteid=po.siteid and workorder.orgid=po.orgid
  left join companies on companies.company = po.vendor and companies.orgid=po.orgid
  left join pluspcustomer on pluspcustomer.customer=workorder.pluspcustomer
  where workorder.wonum='10192'
  group by personid
 ;
```

Comment: You can't `select *` and `group by personid`.  And your error message doesn't look like sql server. Which `select @@version` are you using?

Comment: What don't you understand?  You have `select *` and `group by personid`.  You have a zillion columns that are not in the `group by` and are not in aggregation functions.

Comment: without any aggregate function you cannot just randomly include group by in the last.

Comment: What's the expected output (as an example)?

Comment: i'm new to this sorry, not done much sql - i'm just trying to remove duplicate records so i thought group by would be an option

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you only `GROUP BY personid`, you cannot select everything except `personid`, OR the fields used by aggregate functions such as `SUM`,`MAX`, etc

**UPDATE**

If you just want to **see** the duplicate `personid`, you could use:

```
 select personid 
 from table 
 group by personid
```

But be careful here: If you write query like this, the only field that to determine the duplicate records is `persionid`, if you need to uniquely identify each `persionid` from different `CompanyId`, you need to `group by persionid, CompanyId`, otherwise, same `personId` from different company will be considered as the duplicate records.

But if you want to delete those duplicate records, you should use `ROW_NUMBER()OVER (Partition by persionid Order by your_criteria)` to delete the duplicate records. Try to do some searches to see how does that work, usually I prefer to use that function along with the `CTE table expression`.

Comment: thanks, quite new to this as i haven't done much sql only basic queries - just trying to remove duplicate records and thought group by would be an option

Comment: If you want remove duplicated record use `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 1):

if you just need to remove duplicates, use DISTINCT with your query like this:

your query:

```
SELECT * FROM  .....
```

modify it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM .....
```

Hope it helps.